# What are the differences between ~といわれている, ~とされている and ~と考えられている?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, nuances, verbs

I understand that these verbs related to expressing a certain belief or viewpoint. I frequently confuse the three.

From what I can understand the meanings are:

> **~といわれている**
>
> Repeating or reporting on something that has been said by someone
> else.

> **~とされている & ~と考えられている**
>
> Reporting on a widely held belief or opinion held by others.

Are these descriptions correct, what are the main differences between their usage?

Comment: You meant **widely** in the second. And yes, that is the main difference if any. But all are mostly interchangeable as far as I can think of.